# Find the equation of the tangent line to the curve $3x^3 + 3y^2-11=4xy-x$ at the point $(1,-1)$.

Tags: calculus

The answer choices are given below:

- a) $5x + 7y = -2$
- b) $-7x+5y = -12$
- c) $-5x + 7y = -12$
- d) $7x+5y = - 12$
- e) $-7x + 5y = 2$

Comment: Can you please add the work that you've done on the question?  If this is homework, please read [How to ask a homework question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803/23353) on meta.

Comment: Solve the function like a quadratic equation in terms of $y$. You now have to differentiate that to get the slope of the line.

Answer (score 2):

You want to

- implicitly differentiate both sides of the equation
- solve the resulting equation for $\frac{dy}{dx}$ as a function of $x$ and $y$
- evaluate that expression at $(x,y) = (1,-1)$ to find the slope of the line tangent to the curve at $(1,-1)$.
- Use that slope and the point $(1,-1)$ to find the equation of the line.